# CSRF form validation fires even when form token matches session variable token - MVC

Tags: php

I have a function which generates a value for the form token. That is in a hidden field in the view:

```
<form action="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/users/" method="post">
    <input class="form-email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $data['email']; ?>">
    <input class="form-password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    <input class="login-btn btn-filled" id="login" type="submit" value="Login">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="form_token" value="<?php echo make_form_token(); ?>">
</form>
```

In my controller I have:

```
public function index() 

    {

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

            $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            $password = trim($_POST['password']);

                $data = [

                    'email' => $email,
                    'password' => $password,
                    'message' => ''

                ];

                if(!isset($_SESSION['token']) || $_POST['form_token'] !== $_SESSION['token']) {

                    $data['message'] .= "CSRF token invalid <br />";
                }

                              // other form validation here

                           if(!empty($data['message'])) {

                    $this->view('users/index', $data);

                } else {

// success
```

if I echo out the session variable and view the page source, I can see that the hidden variable value for token is exactly the same as the session variable value. Why then do I keep getting my error message that says the CSRF token is invalid?

The strange thing is that I do exactly the same thing in another area of my website and it works just fine. Very confused...

I also know that the session is set because if I change the validation to just:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
```

then the error goes away. So, it is something to do with the hidden field form token.

Here is the function that creates the token:

```
function make_form_token() {

        $token = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        return $token;

}
```

Comment: You use session_start() in both pages?

Comment: echo `$_SESSION['token']` directly after it being set in the form, then check its the same token in the POST section in the controller, if its different or not set then debug the session.

Comment: @halojoy, session_start() is in my helpers file which is required in my bootstrap file so yes, session_start() is correct

Comment: Basically `if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {` is telling you its not set :/

Comment: I don't get the error if I just have that code which means it is set and if I echo it out I can see the value of the session variable.

Comment: No it means its not set `!isset`.. a session var is just like any other var, but if the session is not working it wont hold upon refresh. Something could be killing the session, enable error reporting, and look for headers already sent etc.

Comment: var_dump() both $_SESSION and the $_POST on the receiving page

Comment: If I just load the page I get: `array(1) { ["token"]=> string(44) "zlfu95MAANaXf2SJoW3ahtgqF0LVXnWN7J8P2A3YcKE=" } 
array(0) { }`

Comment: If I submit the form which basically submits to itself, I get `array(1) { ["token"]=> string(44) "WOqbkgn+97ppteRgYBpEs1XvjJ6xQXzELxYPRl7x3Mk=" }
array(4) { ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["password"]=> string(0) "" ["form_token"]=> string(44) "zlfu95MAANaXf2SJoW3ahtgqF0LVXnWN7J8P2A3YcKE=" ["some-field"]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: Have you got multiple `make_form_token();` in that same view? For example 2 forms?

Comment: Nope. I only have one form in the view

Comment: I use https://github.com/Vundo/CSRF it is simple and works great. You know there are plenty of options out there.

Comment: Your need to update your question with all the code, as something else is happening. The above var_dumps dont make sense, the token is set in get and used in form_token but not the same token once posted, its simply like make_form_token is called twice.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, not sure if it is enough but I added the function to the initial question which creates the session token.

Comment: Another thing I noticed. Underneath the form I have a link to another page (forgot password). On the forgot password page I have a link back to login. If I start on the login page and then click on the link to go to the forgot password page, and then click on the link again to go back to login and submit the form. The tokens match. If I click submit again then they don't match. That is odd behavior.

Comment: I see your user/index page is a method in a class. Where you ave the CSRF check. So, at submission you run this method. Inside the method should be $_SESSION['token'] and $_POST['form_token']. Why it does not work is a big  mystery to me ...

Comment: I figured it out but I don't know why it broke it. `<form action="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/users/" id="loginForm" method="post">` had a slash after /users/ but if I remove it so it is /users then it works just fine